# Blend different size textures in Shader Graph

Tags: unity, unity-shader-graph

Say I've got a character model where part of the face has two UV maps: one's mapped to the generic body texture, the other covers a small area on the face to allow for a highly detailed tattoo.

I want to create a shader graph that will let me dynamically blend the tattoo over the skin texture, but I can't figure out how to process both textures so that they can be fed into a blend node.

Comment: What did you try, and how did the outcome differ from what you want?

Comment: If I just blend two textures together I get a tattoo the size of the whole body texture, whereas I want it to cover a very specific position. Not sure how to get it figure out said position.

Comment: Maybe your question should say and show that. Presumably you considered multiplying the UV coordinate you passed into the tattoo texture sampler?